# navigationBar doesn't appear under ios7 but does in ios 6

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios7

I have the following code

```
else {
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    _navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    _navigationControl.hidden = NO;
  } else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    _navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    _navigationControl.hidden = YES;

  }
}
```

If I compile it, it works fine in iOS6 but it doesn't in ios7. The navbar is meant to appear when the user taps on the screen.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your info.plist file set the key, "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO.